# Add to a file name

Tags: batch-file

I have a lot of files named like this

```
PYHT_YH01_G1_HM_9002-01_SFINP.rpt_20161027115330
```

Need to add `QUAL_PX_PlanConnexion@`:

```
QUAL_PX_PlanConnexion@PYHT_YH01_G1_HM_9002-01_SFINP.rpt.f07_20161027115330
```

How can I do that to over 1200 files fast and simple

Comment: may I introduce you to the [ren](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) command?

Answer (score 1):

just noticed, you also have a change in the extension part, which makes it a little bit more complicated:

```
@echo off
break> PYHT_YH01_G1_HM_9002-01_SFINP.rpt_20161027115330
dir
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.rpt_*) do (
  set "ext=%%~xa"
  ren  "%%a" "QUAL_PX_PlanConnexion@%%~na!ext:_=.f07_!"
)
dir
```

see `for /?`, `set /?` and `ren /?` for details. Also read about [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082).